# Eclipse reports HTML warning for correct (as I assume) code

Tags: java, html, eclipse, servlets

I have a servlet in my application which has its mapping, say “/hello”. Then I have a reference to this servlet in html page: `<a href=”hello”>Hello</a>`.
Eclipse gives a warning for “hello” in html page, saying: “Resource not found: hello”. Anyway, when I start project, everything works. 
My project has standard Web project configuration. Why Eclipse gives such a warning?

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing

```
<a href=”hello”>Hello</a>
```

with

```
<a href="/hello">Hello</a>
```

**Note:** change in quotes

Comment: Oops :) I will delete those comments

Comment: Maybe I judged your eyes too soon ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Where do I get such nice quotes, that will resolve situation? I have only standard quotes on my keyboard.

Comment: copy it from here, I am not sure about your keyboard

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't work (I mean, I copied, but Eclipse still doesn't like it.

Comment: Nope. Same effect: "Resource not found: /hello"

Comment: do you have any resource to be servd at that path ?>

Answer (score 0):

If "hello" is a folder, is there a index.xy-file inside?
If not, you have to add the suffix to your link.
I assume that the hello folder/file is in the directory where the html-file is